# Mimic local history in Eclipse within Talend

Tags: eclipse, versioning, talend

Eclipse IDE has feature that captures log of modified files as a local history. Is this possible to mimic in Talend Studio? i.e. I change job then I save and run job. Two minutes later I change job then I save and run job. Can I revert to previously saved jobs from two minutes ago?

Comment: hey Paul can you please review this question and award an answer or close it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand your question correctly your asking about version control which Talend has.

Simply before each run of your job go to File > Save as then on the dialog box that appears hit the M , or m button (Major or Minor version) then hit finish.

After you have re-versioned the job you can right click on the job in the repository view and click open another version.

The paid version using Github/TAC stores a copy of the code for each run depending on configuration.